# How do i do 'show' statement in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

What command shall I use when I want to know what databases are in mongodb and what collections are in a database (equals to `show tables` statement in SQL )? I only found `{dbStats:1}` in docs that can only show information about current database without a list of collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the [official document](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Overview+-+The+MongoDB+Interactive+Shell#Overview-TheMongoDBInteractiveShell-SelectDatabase):

```
show dbs            displays all the databases on the server you are connected to
use db_name         switches to db_name on the same server
show collections    displays a list of all the collections in the current database
```

Answer (score 0):

It's `show dbs` and `show collections`:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Overview+-+The+MongoDB+Interactive+Shell#Overview-TheMongoDBInteractiveShell-SelectDatabase